# c++ How to place definition of static functors in class implementation file?

Tags: c++17, functor

I'm using static functors (to be used everywhere) defined in the base class like:

```
/* Base.hpp */

class Base {
    ...
    static struct Cpyz_t cpy_z;
};

struct Cpyz_t {
private:
    template<typename U>
    void op(U& dest, mpz_t& z, std::false_type) {
        dest.setz(z);
    }
    template<typename U>
    typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<U>,void>
    op(U& dest, mpz_t& z, std::true_type) const {
        dest = mpz_get_si(z);
    }
    template<typename U>
    typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<U>,void>
    op(U& dest, mpz_t& z, std::true_type) const {
        dest = mpz_get_d(z);
    }
public:
    template<typename U>
    void operator()(U& dest, mpz_t& z) {
        op(dest, z, std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_arithmetic_v<U>>());
    }
};

inline Cpyz_t Base::cpy_z;
```

The code works well: I can call `cpy_z()` from any file (which `#includes Base.hpp`). There are many similar functors. I'd like to place the definitions (struct bodies) in the `Base.cpp` implementation file, because it's a lot of code. Therefore I'm trying:

```
/* Base.hpp */

struct Cpyz_t;      // forward declaration, incomplete type

class Base {
    static struct Cpyz_t cpy_z;
};

/* Base.cpp */

struct Cpyz_t {
    /* same as above */
};

Cpyz_t Base::cpy_z;
```

Now `cpy_z()` can be called only from `Base.cpp`. When called from somewhere else, e.g.

```
/* Somewhere.cpp */

#import "Base.hpp"
...
cpy_z();    // compile error
```

the complainer reports `"Incomplete type in call to object of type 'Cpyz_z'"`. I understand what the problem is.

What is the correct syntax to fix it? I can't instantiate a functor variable in `Base.hpp` (because the definition follows in `Base.cpp`).

Comment: With the second version, the code that includes `Base.hpp` only sees the forward declaration `struct Cpyz_t;`. It can't know that there might be an `operator()`, so `cpy_z()` doesn't make sense. So you need to at least declare the operator in the header. However, that operator is a template, at which point you run into [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Thanks for the comment. I moved the functions to an extra header, which makes more sense anyway.